Java 21 Swing Nimbus: on Windows/Linux high-resolution display the GUI is tiny
There are a lot of old questions regarding the Java Windows/Linux scaling topic with no clear answer. Does some Swing expert know of any updates, for example on Nimbus?
I have coded a really nice Swing application on a computer with 1920x1080 pixel screen. Today I saw the application on a high resolution screen and the app was tiny.
I do not know how to fix this problem. I googled a lot, but could not find a good answer. What I found is JEP 263 https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8055212
It says the issue is resolved. But not how to fix the code?
This is the Nimbus I use:
NimbusLookAndFeel nimbus = new NimbusLookAndFeel();
     UIManager.setLookAndFeel(nimbus);
     UIManager
           .put("control", Color.WHITE);
     UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", ApplicationColors.getLightGrayGold());
     UIManager.put("nimbusBase", ApplicationColors.getDarkGold());
     UIManager.put("textForeground", Color.BLACK);
     UIManager.put("nimbusFocus", ApplicationColors.getSunflowerYellow());
     UIManager
           .put("ToolBar:Button.contentMargins", new Insets(5, 15, 5, 15));
     UIManager
           .put("TextField.background", ApplicationColors.getLightYellow());
     UIManager.put("ComboBox.forceOpaque", false);
     UIManager.put("TitledBorder.border", new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
     UIManager.put("TitledBorder.position", TitledBorder.ABOVE_BOTTOM);
     UIManager.put("TitledBorder.font", ApplicationFonts.getGermanFont(16F));
     UIManager.put("TitledBorder.titleColor", Color.GRAY);
     UIManager.put("Table.opaque", false);
     UIManager.put("List.opaque", false);
     UIManager.put("Table.cellRenderer", false);
     UIManager.put("OptionPane.buttonFont", ApplicationFonts.getGermanFont(16F));

     UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.ABBRECHEN));
     UIManager.put("OptionPane.yesButtonText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.JA));
     UIManager.put("OptionPane.noButtonText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.NEIN));
     UIManager.put("OptionPane.titleText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.BILD_LOESCHEN));
     
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.openButtonText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.OEFFNEN));
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.ABBRECHEN));
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.saveButtonText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.SPEICHERN));
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonToolTipText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.ABBRECHEN_DER_AUSWAHL));
     UIManager
           .put("FileChooser.saveButtonToolTipText",
                 translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.AUSGEWAEHLTE_DATEI_SPEICHERN));
     UIManager
           .put("FileChooser.openButtonToolTipText",
                 "Ausgewählte Datei öffnen");
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.upFolderToolTipText", "Eine Ebene höher");
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.homeFolderToolTipText", "Home");
     UIManager
           .put("FileChooser.newFolderToolTipText",
                 "Neuen Ordner erstellen");
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewButtonToolTipText", "Liste");
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewButtonToolTipText", "Details");
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.lookInLabelText", "Suchen in:");
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameLabelText", "Dateiname:");
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText", "Dateityp:");
     UIManager
           .put("FileChooser.acceptAllFileFilterText",
                 "Alle Dateien (*.*)");
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.folderNameLabelText", "Ordnername:");
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.openDialogTitleText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.OEFFNEN));
     UIManager.put("FileChooser.saveDialogTitleText", translator.realisticTranslate(Translation.SPEICHERN));
     UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", ApplicationColors.getWhite());

How to go about scaling on high DPI Windows/Linux screens?
UPDATE
I found this on the internet:
The Per-monitor DPI-aware value means the following:
true - JRE-managed HiDPI
false - IDE-managed HiDPI

If you need to test IDE with scale 1.0 there're two options:
In JRE-managed HiDPI mode:
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=true
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0

In IDE-managed HiDPI mode:
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false
-Dide.ui.scale=1.0

I will test this and report as soon as possible.
UPDATE
The minimal app example would be to much code, since I use my own Layout Managers extended from LayoutManager2. Of course I set sizes on the UI. But it still should scale.
UPDATE
If you want to see the scaling problem, you can download the software Cerebrummi for free from heise.de/download
software download
The software Cerebrummi needs Java 21 jdk to run.
The software Cerebrummi can be set to display in English if you click on the flag in the top row and choose English.
UPDATE
I followed Holgers advice and tested a small example with some features from my large software and IT DID SCALE on high resolution screen. So it is something in my Software that I have to find.
UPDATE
I found the offending code:
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (ApplicationImages.getImage() != null)
      {
         float factorWidth = getParent().getWidth() / 1280F;
         float factorHeight = getParent().getHeight() / 859F;
         if (factorWidth < factorHeight)
         {
            int width = (int) (1280F * factorHeight);
            int x = getParent().getWidth() / 2 - width / 2;
            g.drawImage(
              
ApplicationImages.getImage().getScaledInstance(width,
                    getParent().getHeight(), 
BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH),
              x, 0, this);
         }
         else
         {
            int height = (int) (859F * factorWidth);
            int y = getParent().getHeight() / 2 - height / 2;
        
g.drawImage(ApplicationImages.getImage().getScaledInstance(
              getParent().getWidth(), height, 
BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH),
              0, y, this);
        }
     }
  }

It is the large image in the background of the first screenshot!!! How to fix the code?




Add the line System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1"); as the first line of your code.  The "1" means 100% Windows scaling.  Change the number to whatever scaling you want.

Then also add the setProperty line as the last line on your code.

It will not affect other Java apps.  System properties changed by code are not permanent.  When the program exits, the system property change ceases to exist.

ResourceBundle

Unfortunately the scaling is not working. I have to use the compatibility modus and set the icon sizing to 175%.

There seems to be a huge misunderstanding. Forcing the scale to 1.0 is explicitly requesting a tiny UI. This property has been the solution for people who have too many bitmap graphics in their UI¹, which looks bad when scaled. So forcing the scale to 1.0 would make the UI tiny but crisp for them. So if you do not want a tiny UI but the desktop default scaling, don’t specify these options.            ¹ or double buffering not taking the actual scale into account

@Holger I set the ide.ui.scale to 1.7 but the UI stays tiny on my high resolution Windows laptop.

The first attempt should be not to specify any of those options, further, try a minimal application to ensure that there are no actions within the application affecting the scaling behavior. If that still has the issue, provide the minimal example here, together with a complete description of the environment, e.g. which Java version.

@Holger Of course I use layout managers and set sizes inside the large program. The minimal app would reveal my layout managers that implement LayoutManager2. This would be to much code and I do not want to reveal that. Now I chose the second option. It works fine on low resolution screen and can be manually adjusted by high resolution windows screens.

@Holger What kind of actions besides setting minimum and maximum sizes could affect the scaling behavior?

I don’t think that setting minimum and maximum sizes affects scaling behavior. Most notably, there are system properties affecting the behavior, as you already know, so changing the system properties somewhere may affect the behavior. Besides that, custom launchers (which may not have the DPI aware flag set) or code changing the transformations of Graphics2D are candidates for affecting the scaling behavior. But you really should just set up a minimal Swing program (not derived from your program, just a ten liner or so) first and see whether it has the same problem in the same environment.

@Holger Thank you I will check on that and make that example.

@Holger I found the offending code. Now how to fix it? The image is supposed to adjust to size changes in the window.

@Holger Please write an answer to I can select it as the right one.

Thank you very, very much to @Holger.
Now I learned:
Do NOT set the System scaling options!!!
The offending code could be fixed with:
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (ApplicationImages.getImage() != null)
      {
         float factorWidth = 1536 / 1280F; // here is the fix
         float factorHeight = 960 / 859F; // here is the fix
         if (factorWidth < factorHeight)
         {
            int width = (int) (1280F * factorHeight);
            int x = getParent().getWidth() / 2 - width / 2;
            g.drawImage(
                  ApplicationImages.getImage().getScaledInstance(width,
                    getParent().getHeight(), BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH),
              x, 0, this);
         }
         else
         {
            int height = (int) (859F * factorWidth);
            int y = getParent().getHeight() / 2 - height / 2;
            g.drawImage(ApplicationImages.getImage().getScaledInstance(
              getParent().getWidth(), height, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH),
              0, y, this);
         }
      }
   }


You can use drawImage with size referring to the component’s size without a factor, to scale to the right size. Then, you don’t need getScaledInstance. Use setRenderingHint on the graphics (which is always a Graphics2D since Java 2), to request smooth scaling when needed.

@Holger Please write an answer.

Not enough time today, but after the holidays, I can do.
